# Is there any easy backend interface for Virtuemart 2?

Tags: magento, joomla, virtuemart

I am Joomla Developer. 
Is there any easy backend interface for Virtuemart 2? 
Whenever I install VM2 for anybody, they are unable to understand it easily. Please guide me if there is any thirdparty extension exists which brings its own backend interface for virtuemart.

Additionally, I like Magento backend, but I don't have developing experience in Magento. So I cannot work in magento. But I like its backend. If there is any extension which brings backend interface similar to that of magento but in Joomla then I really appreciate it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, whilst commercial, I like the backend of k2Mart:

http://k2martdemo.joomlaworks.net/

http://www.joomlaworks.net/extensions/commercial-premium/k2mart

Comment: Is it Easy to understand just like Magento?

Comment: I've never used Magneto so couldn't say! Ask the developers if there's a way you can get a feel for the backend. But I would say if you've ever tried k2 - its basically exactly the same as the back end of k2 (as it is basically a k2/virtuemart bridge)

Comment: Thanks for answer. Looks like it is closer to what I am looking for.